# mongoose populate references in same collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have ItemCatalog collection which contains type ,unit, items.

```
var Categories = new Schema({
  typeName: String
});


var MeasurementUnit = new Schema({
  unit: String
});

var Items = new Schema({
 itemName: String,
 itemStrength: String,
 idType: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Categories' },
 idUnit: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MeasurementUnit' },
 isActive: Boolean
});


var ItemCatalog = new Schema({
 type: Categories,
 unit: MeasurementUnit,
 items: Items
});
```

document of collection looking like below

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("57b188d67aa27ae4ee87e11c"),
"type": [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57b188d6e128064381ae2f2f"),
        "typeName" : "abc"
    }
],
"__v": 0,
"unit": [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57b188e4e128064381ae2f54"),
        "unit" : "mg"
    }
],
"items": [ 
    {
        "itemStrength" : "100",
        "itemName" : "a1",
        "idType" : ObjectId("57b188d6e128064381ae2f2f"),
        "idUnit" : ObjectId("57b188e4e128064381ae2f54"),
        "isActive" : true,
        "_id" : ObjectId("57b188f3e128064381ae2f7a")
    }
 ]
}
```

How can I retrieve items data which are active and populating idType and idUnit  instead of fetching entire document and looping at the client?

Want data something like this

```
{
_id: "57b188d67aa27ae4ee87e11c",
drugs: [
        {
            itemStrength: "100",
            itemName: "a1",
            typeName: "abc",
            unit: "mg",
            isActive: true,
            _id: "57b188f3e128064381ae2f7a"
        }
     ]
 }
```

Please suggest best ways implement same.

Comment: I don't think it's possible using population, because `type` and `unit` are stored as [sub documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) and not in a separate collection.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ItemCatalog.find({"items.isActive" : true},{'items.$' : 1}).populate('items.$.idType').populate('items.$.idUnit').exec(function(err,result){...});
```

`items.isActive` to required check which is active.

`items.$` is provided to return only those elements of items array which are active.

`item.$.idType` is required to populate only from matched array element.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: is your `items` an `array of item` or just a single `item`? similarly `type` and `unit` are `array` or just a single `category` a,d `measurementUnit` respectively or `array` of those?